# Is it possible to call C# dll from Python in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, python-3.x

I have developed an app in Python under Raspbian (on a Raspberry Pi) and I need to call some methods from a C# dll that was not developed by me.

I have previously called methods from a C# dll in Windows, using [Pythonnet](http://pythonnet.github.io/).

But in this case the app is running under Linux and I do not know if I can call the methods. So is it possible to call a C# dll in Python under Linux? If so, how?

Comment: @Valkyrie OK, but is there a solution? Maybe recompiling the DLL under NET Core or Mono?

Comment: For a Net App to run you either need the Net Library installed of publish application.  The publish updates Windows dlls so app will run without Net.  Many of the Net libraries are just wrappers that call Windows dlls and will not run without the compatible dlls installed on machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call any kind of .NET code, you'll need a runtime for it.

For Mono, you'll want to look at this: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/.

If you find the embedding procedure too complex, you might want to write a wrapper for the library that can communicate over some message passing protocol (TCP/IP, shared memory, etc.), for which you can easily serialize/deserialize in both .NET and Python, and run it in its own process.